# Symfony2 Doctrine - Delete or hide relation to keep consistency?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a Symfony2 project with many relations and I want the dataset to be consistent at any time.
For example, a sale is linked to a product.

If the user decides to delete the product, but the product is linked to sales, how to keep the sale object consistent ?

With plain SQL, I would have added a "hidden" column, with a RESTRICT relation.
If there is no sales linked to the product, the product is deleted.
If there one or more sales, the product is not deleted but the hidden field is set to true.

In the user interface, the SQL request would be

```
     SELECT * FROM product WHERE hidden = FALSE
```

Is it the right way to handle this problem ?
Have you any ideas how to have a similar behaviour in Symfony 2 ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Doctrine's annotations](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/annotations-reference.html) to help you keep your data consistent at all times. For instance, when a sale is deleted it would proceed to delete the product as well.

If you are using a one-to-one or a one-to-many relationship you can annotate **orphanRemoval** as true:

> orphanRemoval: Boolean that specifies if orphans, inverse OneToOne
>   entities that are not connected to any owning instance, should be
>   removed by Doctrine. Defaults to false.

See [here](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-onetoone) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't want the sale to be deleted, nor the product. That's the problem. The sale history must be consistent, even if the admin has "deleted" the product.

Comment: I finally used the DoctrineExtensions Bundle, which has the "SoftDeletable" feature.